# Google Search Console - Verification Failed

Tags: wordpress, web-crawler, google-search, googlebot, google-search-console

I am trying to add my website to Google Search Console but failed, it returns

`The connection to your server timed out`

The file is there,  I can open it on the normal browser, all meta tag set to `index,all`, `robots.txt` is added and have `User-agent: * Disallow:` allowing everything to be crawled.

But it seems I coudn't let Search Console check the verification file, I have tried using the HTML File Verification, HTML Tag Verification, Google Analytics Verification, and Google Tag Verification. But all of them returning the same error , connection time out.

Is there anything else I have to do to verify this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you have it on two lines like so: ?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Comment: Yes, it is in 2 lines like that. Not sure what is the other reason the page couldn't be crawled